# Ember Where to place data for common code like notification, user profile on navbar

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-2

I have writing a common navigation for my ember application. I have place my outlet tag inside navigation in application.hbs. Now I want to pass some dynamic data to my navbar, how should I do it. I see there is nothing as ApplicationController in latest versions of ember. So Where should I place my data for all such things.

Comment: you can create application controller by running `ember generate controller application`

Answer (score 0):

there might be a file called controller/application.js